# Response Time in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have installed response-time on my development environment

main.ts

```
app.use(
    responseTime((req: any, res: any, time: any) => {
        console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url} ${time}`);
    })
);
```

And api.ts

```
router.post('/disconnect', async (req, res, next) => {
    .....
    next();
});
```

But the problem is console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url} ${time}`); is not displaying on console when i hit API endpoint? what am i missing

Comment: technically you should place your code in `res.on("finish",` else the timing won't be accurate, it will fire before its actually responded

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the response-time middleware assignment before the router assignment? As far as I can see the order makes a difference.

I've tested this out and the following trivial code works.

```
const express = require('express')
const responseTime = require('response-time')

const router = express.Router()
const app = express()

app.use(
    responseTime((req, res, time) => {
        console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url} ${time}`);
    })
);

app.use('/router/', router);

router.post('/disconnect', async (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('POST');
    next();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

If I do:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/router/disconnect
```

I see a log output like:

```
POST /disconnect 2.5177
```

But if I switch the order of the middleware like so:

```
app.use('/router/', router);

app.use(
    responseTime((req, res, time) => {
        console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url} ${time}`);
    })
);
```

I don't see any output at all.